# Display a confirmation message on Delete a record from a Grid

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to display a confirmation message when the User delete a record from a grid this what I implement but I have the error message

With the code below the record is deleted but :

1. the record still in the Grid I have to refresh to see it disapear;
2. I Have the message Error! even if the record is deleted
   3.

   ```
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete Student", "Delete", new { @StudentID = StudentID }, new { @class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil", @id=StudentID })

   $(document).ready(function () {

       $('a.delete').click(OnDeleteClick);

   });

   function OnDeleteClick(e)
   { 
       var StudentId = e.target.id; 
       var flag = confirm('You are about to delete this record permanently. Are you sure you want to delete this record?');

       if (flag) { 
           $.ajax({
               url: '/Home/DeleteRecord',
               type: 'POST', 
               data: { StudentID: StudentId },
               dataType: 'json', 
               success: function (result) { 
                      alert(result); 
                      $("#" + StudentId).parent().parent().remove(); 
                      },
               error: function () { 
                      alert('Error!'); 
                      }
           });
       }
       return false;
   }
   ```

Controller :

```
    public ActionResult DeleteRecord(string StudentID)
    {
       //Code to delete
        }
        return RedirectToAction("StudentGrid",
                     "Home");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing which grid you are using try the following:

Get the closest tr tag so you can remove it on success with:

```
var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
$tr.remove();
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tfrhdgkw/1/)**

Set the content message from your controller, the Redirect won't work as it is an ajax call.

```
 public ActionResult DeleteRecord(string StudentID)
 {
    var success = false;
    //Code to delete
    // then set success variable
    if (success)
    {
        return Content("Deleted");
    }
    else
    {
        return Content("Failed");
    }          
 }
```

Then from your success handler check the message and remove if needed, the client-side code would end up like this:

```
function OnDeleteClick(e)
{ 
    e.preventDefault();
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");  
    var StudentId = e.target.id; 
    var flag = confirm('You are about to delete this record permanently. Are you sure you want to delete this record?');

    if (flag) { 
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/DeleteRecord',
            type: 'POST', 
            data: { StudentID: StudentId },
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function (result) { 
                   if (result == "Deleted")
                        $tr.remove();  
                   },
            error: function () { 
                   alert('Error!'); 
                   }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I am using GridMVC your code work for the message but the Grid is not refreshed

Comment: @melom Sorry, I'm not sure how to refresh the GridMVC. I would create another question that is specifically about that. Someone will answer pretty quickly I'm sure, I've not used it for ages. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   public ActionResult DeleteRecord(string StudentID)
    {
        //Code to delete
    }
     return Json("Record Is Delete", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
```

with is response from controller you can show this MSG in alert() 
with update grid in project you can use below code is sufficient

```
$(e).closest("tr").remove();
```