# Refresh a GridMVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I want to refresh the GridMVC after a delete.

StudentsGrid.cshtml :

```
@model IEnumerable<AWS.Models.GroupedStudents>

@using GridMvc.Html
@{
   Layout = null;
 }
 ....

  //The Grid
  @Html.Partial("TheGridContents")
  ....
```

in the controller I check if the record is deleted, if it's deleted I want to refresh only the Grid, if it's not I am displaying an error message:

```
public ActionResult DeleteRecord(string StudentID)
{
   var success = false;
    //All my code to delete the Row

   if (success)
       return RedirectToAction("StudentsGrid", "Home"); //Refresh
   else
       return Content("Failed");  
}
```

this is a part of :

[Display a confirmation message on Delete a record from a Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203954/display-a-confirmation-message-on-delete-a-record-from-a-grid/31204681?noredirect=1#comment50417488_31204681)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When I delete a record from the Grid this record will not be displayed, now the Record is still shown in the Grid, the User had to refresh the page to see the record disapear

Comment: yes it is please seee: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203954/display-a-confirmation-message-on-delete-a-record-from-a-grid/31204681?noredirect=1#comment50417488_31204681

Comment: You dont do anything with the content of the returned ajax call. You need to also keep all your code in one place